# How do adjacent parentheses in JavaScript functions work, and where is this documented?

Tags: javascript

Before you flag this as a duplicate, note: I understand what an IIFE is. This question is not about IIFE's.

The question: why is JavaScript able to parse adjacent parentheses, even in a standard function call? How does this construct - `myFunction()()` - work? For example, here's a bit of code from a test using Jasmine:

```
var element = compile('<div my-directive></div>')(scope);
```

Why would we go this route rather than passing the scope as the second argument? I don't believe this has anything to do with the keeping the global environment clean, and I can't find a thing about this particular construct anywhere, except where it concerns IIFE's. Is there a name for this construct?

Most importantly, please provide some sort of authoritative reference (link to mdn, ecmascript spec, etc).

Comment: You make this sound so formal like you're demanding proof.  It's not complicated at all.  If `compile()` returns a function reference, then the next set of parens execute the function that was returned and pass it a single argument.  Parens in this context in javascript execute the function reference that came right before.  Same as they do with `alert("Hello");`.  In this case, the second set of parens operations on the return value from the `compile()` function which is a function reference.

Comment: @jfriend00 definitely not demanding. I understand it's not complicated to you - I needed help understanding this concept, and couldn't find it specifically documented anywhere. The answers below have provided that help, makes sense now.

Comment: Your call for an "authoritative reference" made it sound like you wouldn't trust a simple explanation (which seemed odd to me).  But alas it looks like you were OK with an explanation which is good.

Comment: I was under the impression that this was a pattern (such as IIFE's, which have a name and are widely written about), rather than being a very simple and inherent feature of JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the result of two rules:

1. The return value of function calls may be used immediately (no need to assign to a variable).
2. Functions are objects (they can be assigned to variables, passed as arguments and returned from function calls).

The first rule means that if you have code that does this:

```
function a () { return { hello : 'world' } }
```

You can do this:

```
a().hello; // returns 'world';
```

Which is basically the same as doing this without using any temporary variables:

```
var tmp = a();
tmp.hello; // value is 'world';
```

The second rule means that you can do this:

```
function b () { return function () { alert('hello world') } }
var c = b();
c(); // alerts 'hello world';
```

Combining rule 1 and rule 2 means the above can be rewritten as:

```
b()(); // alerts 'hello world';
```

Answer (score 1):

`compile('<div my-directive></div>')` must return a function which has a `scope` argument.

Maybe it would look something like this:

```
function compile(stringArg){
  return function(scopeArg){
    if(typeof scopeArg === 'object'){
      console.log(stringArg);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So you could nest a third function and call via compile()()()?

Comment: If your second function returns another one, yes. In my opinion, you should study Constructors and Objects, to avoid that kind of function creation.

Comment: `if(scopeArg === 'scope'` is invalid code as you're trying to do string comparison on an object (if this is Angular or something similar). A more likely scenario is that you're compiling the directive and passing in scope to tell it which variables to populate the template with.

Comment: I changed it, but truth be told you don't know what scope was supposed to be. It could be a variable that holds a String for all I know.

Answer (score 1):

This has everything to do with closures. What's happening is that `compile()` must return a function that takes a variable, in this case `scope`.

Let's look at a simpler example:

```
function adder (first) {
  return function (second) {
    return first + second;
  };
};

adder(2)(3);
// returns 5

var add2 = adder(2);
// add2 now equals function (second) { return 2 + second; }

add2(4);
// returns 6
```

Often, a reason why you'd do this is because you want to reuse a function in a lot of ways. In the case of `compile`, you could run compile once, and reuse it with a number of different objects (or scopes). Also, you can make a number of variations with it.

i.e. The example above could be `adder3`, `adder4`, etc.

Compile probably has some behavior like this:

```
function compile(html) {
  // Some code here to turn string template into something more useable
  return function (scope) {
    // Scope being an object with values to plug into a template
    return DOM_element;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, great explanation. Are you aware of any documentation, or of a specific name for this construct? All closures don't look like this.

Comment: @ShawnErquhart : you could check http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-closures-with-ease/

Comment: The OP has **nothing** to do with closures. You've introduced a closure in the example, but it isn't required.

Comment: @RobG `compile` returns a closure that takes a scope object as an argument. @Shawn Here's a book that might help: https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS But in this particular case, there is a strong DOM aspect to understanding how templating is down in JS.

Comment: @RobG Can you explain why it doesn't have to do with closures and provide an example? I don't think that's true, but I'd love to see an example if it is.

Comment: All that is required is that the first function return another function, there is no requirement for a closure. `function foo(arg){console.log(arg)} function bar(){return foo} bar()('hey');`

Comment: I see your point on how it can be done without closures, but I can't think of a situation where you'd do that without a closure, and the question asked absolutely uses a closure; thus, saving a reference to the template.

Comment: The overall concept itself has nothing to do with closures.  The first function could return an external function that was not in any closure.  Thus, you should not be making an answer that makes it seem like the core concept here depends upon a closure.  It does not.   `function compile() { return alert;};  compile()("Hello")`.  No closure.  You can return a reference to a function that's in a closure if you want, but that is entirely optional and not part of the core concept of what the parens do.  Yes, the `compile()` example does likely use a closure.